# Oracle - Add rows together in one field

Tags: sql, plsql

Using the following code.  Keep getting the following error

```
Select distinct 
    ship_L.ship_ID,
    ship_L.Item_Num,
    C.sku,
    C.ob_oid,
    c.Container
From (
    Select distinct
        ob_oid,
        sku,
        substr((ltrim(sys_Connect_By_Path(trim(to_Cont),' / '))),2,(length(ltrim(sys_Connect_By_Path(trim(to_Cont),' / '))))) as Container
    From (
        Select distinct
            Ob_oid,
            sku,
            To_Cont,
            row_number() Over (Partition by sku order by to_Cont) -1 as seq
        From (
            Select distinct
                ob_oid,
                sku,
                To_Cont
            from elite_76_w1.ITH_f
            --Where ob_oid = '237472'
            --  and sku = '64154'
            )  
        )
        Where  connect_By_Isleaf = 1
          Connect by seq = Prior seq +1 and sku = Prior sku
          Start with seq = 1
) C 
Left  Join elite_76_D.ship_L
    on ship_L.ship_id = C.ob_oid
    and ship_L.item_num = C.sku

WHere C.ob_oid = '237472'
and C.sku = '64154'
```

Getting this error:
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long 01489.  00000 - " result of string concatenation is too long" *Cause:  String concatenatin result is more than the maximun size. * Action: Make sure that the result is lees than the maximum size.  Vendor Code 1489Error at line 3.

Start with:
SKU       Location
64154     A153945
64154     A153943
64154     A153947
64154     A153946
64154     A153944

Need:
64154      A153944 / A153945 / A153946 / A153947

Thank you for all the help,
David

Comment: As this is a guess, I'll comment and not post. In your inner most query cast "to_cont" to a larger VARCHAR(). For example, it it is a VARCHAR(32), cast it to VARCHAR(4000). ***[All on the assumption that your output field is being limitted to the same length as your input, this may therefor allow more characters in your output.]*** If 4000 isn't going to be enough, you can look at CLOB, but there is a good chance the rest of your code doesn't work with that data type.

Comment: TSQL is for MSSQL. This question is Oracle.

Comment: No luck.  Even when I cast "to_Cont" to 4000 everwhere I use the field, I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long` means that part of your SQL is generating a string longer than 4000 characters, which is the limit of a VARCHAR2 in SQL.

You can't truncate the string in SQL (e.g. with SUBSTR), because SQL needs to construct the string *before* it sends it to the SUBSTR function; and it bails because it exceeds the limit.

To solve this you'll probably need to create your own PL/SQL function, in which you have a greater length limit (32k) for VARCHAR2s.